# How to use a Python class in a Java program?

Tags: java, class, function, python-2.7, methods

Let's suppose I need to write a Java application and this application need to perform some tasks and I have a Python class that perform those tasks through its functions/methods.

I'd like to use this Python class methods/functions in my Java application, is it possible? Note that I'm talking about reading the output.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ,you can with [Jython.](http://www.jython.org/)

> Jython programs can import and use any Java class. Except for some standard modules, Jython programs use Java classes instead of Python modules.

And the [integration](http://www.slideshare.net/onyame/mixing-python-and-java)